# How to get the version of lucene index in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr8

My use case: I am currently on solr 5.5 and upgrading to solr 8.8

For this, I will need to do re-indexing on all machines where solr is installed. I need to do a check on the index version, if the index is made from the old version, then I will run the re-indexing logic, and if it already is the new version, I will skip the re-indexing.

Is there a way to detect the index version?

NOTE: the config files will already be updated to the new version so cannot use  tag from solrconfig.xml

Comment: in your case its a major upgrade...you have re-index all the data...

Comment: Yes I understand that, but we want to avoid multiple re-indexing, so have to detect if re-indexing was already done.

Comment: It's up to your application or solr client to deal with the indexing logic, and thus to "know" what is indexed and what is to be (re)indexed, when this should happen etc. Now, even if the reindexing is triggered manually, don't you have some data in your database keeping track of (at least) the document's last indexing date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP GET request to retrive the info :

```
yoursolrhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system
```

It would be something like below

```
http://yoursolrhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system?wt=json
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still detects the version from what is in the configuration files, not the version of the actual physical index

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the lucene CheckIndex Tool instead, if you have direct access to the index on the file system.

(Note: You must stop the solr service before executing, else there will be an error.)

```
java -cp lucene-core-9.3.0.jar:lucene-backward-codecs-9.3.0.jar org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /path/to/index/
```

Then you should see the index version in the output:

```
Checking index with threadCount: 12
0.78% total deletions; 290597 documents; 2255 deletions
Segments file=segments_7d numSegments=13 version=8.11.1 id=bmwtml5nan76oxh53jblk3hjg userData={commitCommandVer=1729352676019273728, commitTimeMSec=1649239231128}
1 of 13: name=_2us maxDoc=2
    version=8.11.1
    id=2alyagqpio6wye81jr09czfg9
    codec=Lucene87
    compound=false
    numFiles=18
    size (MB)=0.036
    diagnostics = {java.version=1.8.0_312, java.vm.version=25.312-b07, lucene.version=8.11.1, source=flush, os.arch=amd64, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07, os.version=5.4.0-107-generic, java.vendor=Private Build, os=Linux, timestamp=1648810655017}
```

In this example, i used the tool from version 9 to check an index which was created with version 8.
But remember: The libraries you use might only be compatible with the current + the previous lucene index version. So if you use JARs from lucene 9 it will work checking indexes from 9+8, but not from 7.

see also:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html

(The usage is similar to the IndexUpgrader described in the documentation:)
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/indexupgrader-tool.html